# MOSFET switch not switching

Tags: mosfet, circuit-design

I'm comfortable using BJTs but this is the first time I've used MOSFETs.  I'm having to drive a larger current (>500mA) so it was this or using loads of BJTs to share the load.

I've created the circuit below:

[image: Simple MOSFET]

It's to drive an electromagnet at 24VDC.  The magnet has ≈ 200Ω so I represented that by the resistor R1.

When it's *closed* it seems to do what I expected, allow current to flow.

[image: Simple MOSFET]

When I put the gate to ground though I expected the current to stop flowing (or reduce to a negligible level) however all I'm seeing is a small decrease.

[image: Simple MOSFET]

Comment: Try swapping source and drain on the MOSFET. Drawing it upside down isn't helping.

Comment: Anyway, there are plenty of BJTs that will handle way more than 500mA

Comment: @Finbarr There are, but I have 2N3904s available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

[image]

What matters is the voltage between gate and source. This way you apply the 5V where it is needed.

Comment: I misunderstood the terms _drain_ and _source_.  I assumed that the current would flow from the _source_ → _drain_

Comment: Source in this context means the source of electrons.

Comment: current actually does flow from the source to the drain, but  conventional current flow pretends the opposite is true, leading to confusion on this, diode, transistor symbols, etc...

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the full diagram for the MOSFET it should become obvious why connecting it backwards causes it to conduct all the time:

[image]

The body diode between source and drain gets forward biased, so it conducts regardless of Vgs (which will be either -19V or -24V depending on the switch position).